# Populate asp-page from Model variable

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm developing a personal website and blog in ASP.NET Core with Razor pages and appear to be having an issue populating the asp-page helper within a div.

The Model based logic within the HTML is structured as so:

```
@if (Model.LatestBlogs.Any())
{
    foreach (var blog in Model.LatestBlogs)
    {
        <div style="list-style-type:none;"><a asp-page="@blog.BlogPageLink">@blog.BlogTitle</a></div>
    }
}
else
{
    <div style="list-style-type:none;">Theres no blogs yet! Check back soon!</div>
}
```

This works as expected bar populating the asp-page aspect, which in the final render comes up as this:

```
<div style="list-style-type:none;"><a href="">Leadsership vs Management</a></div>
<div style="list-style-type:none;"><a href="">FizzBuzz - The Interview</a></div>
<div style="list-style-type:none;"><a href="">Patience is Key</a></div>
<div style="list-style-type:none;"><a href="">In Memory Data</a></div>
<div style="list-style-type:none;"><a href="">Welcome to the Blog!</a></div>
```

As you can see, the asp-page helper is empty which prevents any navigation.

Here is an example of the data that gets passed from the data access:

```
new BlogSummary { BlogTitle = "Welcome to the Blog!", BlogPageLink = "//Blog//WelcomeToTheBlog", PublishDate = new DateTime(2020, 6, 10) },
```

I've tried single backslashes in the BlogPageLink, using verbatim literal and no joy. Does anyone know how I could do this if its even possible?

Comment: why do you need to use asp-page?  have you tried just using href instead?

Comment: well blow me that worked! Thanks @Danimal - feel like such a newbie now!